# Graphical output problem when using ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm currently trying to see the impact of one parameter on an equation.

To do so, I plot the results of my equation following against a range of values for this parameter by using `ParametricPlot`.

The plot is really skewed and practically impossible to read. All other plots that I do are working on my Mathematica, and even if I reset my workspace, the problem persists. I guess this come from something pretty dumb, but I can't see what. Any idea ?

Here is my code:

```
Umax = 10000000; 
i2 = 0.0000001; 
ParametricPlot[{((i2*Umax)/u2), u2}, {u2, 0.01, 1}]
```

And here is the resulting plot (I enlarged it to the max):

[image]

Isn't the plot supposed to have its x-axis and y-axis automatically balanced ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I feel a little dumb asking this question. If the answer is obvious and relative to a pretty dumb human error, please tell me if I should delete this question. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html). Try, for instance, `ParametricPlot[{i2*Umax/u2, u2}, {u2, 0.01, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`, which is the default aspect ratio utilized e.g. by `Plot`. Adding `PlotRange -> All` is also a good idea to avoid truncation in your horizontal axis.

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Could you please write it as an answer (if you feel this question should be answered) so I can accept it as a valid one? thanks again.

Comment: Sure, I've added it. This question is still likely to be closed as "off topic" because the solution is in the docs. Indeed, I have voted to close as well. I just wanted to make sure that you know that it is *not* a judgment on the quality of the question, which I have voted up because it was well written and it contained all info to answer it, but simply a "housekeeping" move.

Comment: @MarcoB Anyhow, almost everything is in the docs *somewhere*, but this counterintuitive behavior isn't mentioned in the logical place (`ParametricPlot - Possible Issues`), so there's no need for OP to feel bad for asking!

Comment: Thanks you for your comments and advises! I can see perfectly why this question could be off topic although I also agree with Chris K. I still struggle to connect my global Mathematica understanding on different functions such as `Plot` and `ParametricPlot`. But I'm getting better :-D!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, I believe you are looking for [`AspectRatio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html).

Try, for instance,

```
ParametricPlot[
  {i2*Umax/u2, u2}, {u2, 0.01, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`1/GoldenRatio` happens to be the default aspect ratio utilized e.g. by `Plot`. Adding `PlotRange -> All` is also a good idea here to avoid truncation in your horizontal axis.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jerobou No problem, glad to help!